# iOS Test Multiple Regions/Domains with Same Language

Tags: iphone, ios, multilingual

Is there a way to support "Latin" Spanish and "Castilian" Spanish in the same app?  And if there is, how do you test it?

I'm currently supporting several languages, and I have all the language files in the app, but I can't seem to get the language to switch in the simulator or on a device by changing the region.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes across this post, I found that iOS only supports one version of Spanish.  The list is found in the international language settings on each device and the region controls the display of time and dates.